# issue in comparing dataFrame with date format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, compare

i have a serie of data composed with columns and i want to extract the lines where "dateRep" is suprior of one date "x"

```
x= datetime.datetime(2020,3,25)
save_df=df[(df["countriesAndTerritories"]=="Algeria") & (to_datetime(df["dateRep"])> x)]
```

but i always got some date who is inferior to "X"
[image]

[image]

```
177 06/04/2020  6   4   2020    69  22  Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
178 05/04/2020  5   4   2020    80  25  Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
179 04/04/2020  4   4   2020    185 42  Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
183 31/03/2020  31  3   2020    73  4   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
184 30/03/2020  30  3   2020    57  2   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
185 29/03/2020  29  3   2020    45  3   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
186 28/03/2020  28  3   2020    42  1   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
187 27/03/2020  27  3   2020    65  4   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
188 26/03/2020  26  3   2020    38  2   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
202 12/03/2020  12  3   2020    0   0   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
203 09/03/2020  9   3   2020    3   0   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
204 06/03/2020  6   3   2020    5   0   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
205 05/03/2020  5   3   2020    7   0   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
206 04/03/2020  4   3   2020    2   0   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
226 12/02/2020  12  2   2020    0   0   Algeria DZ  DZA 42228429.0  Africa
```

Comment: The output seems correct, e.g. `26/4/2020` is greater than `25/3/2020`, what is the problem? Also, if you can, please post data as text, not as an image.

Comment: the image don't contain all the output, i had problem in uploading the second picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, `pd.to_datetime` will interpret and parse e.g. the string `04/03/2020` as month/day/year ([see the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)). However in your case, you seem to have day/month/year as input format so you need to set the `dayfirst` keyword to `True`. Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

x = datetime(2020, 3, 25)

df = pd.DataFrame({'dateRep': ['04/03/2020', '01/04/2020', '13/06/2019', '05/04/2020'],
                   'countriesAndTerritories': ['Algeria', 'Algeria', 'tmp', 'tmp'],
                   'v': [0, 1, 0, 0]})

df[(df["countriesAndTerritories"]=="Algeria") & (pd.to_datetime(df["dateRep"], dayfirst=True) > x)]

#       dateRep countriesAndTerritories  v
# 1  01/04/2020                 Algeria  1
```

if you omit the keyword, the results will be invalid:

```
df[(df["countriesAndTerritories"]=="Algeria") & (pd.to_datetime(df["dateRep"]) > x)]
#       dateRep countriesAndTerritories  v
# 0  04/03/2020                 Algeria  0
```

Final remark: if you want to be safe, specify the format of the date(time) string explicitly, here e.g. in `pd.to_datetime(df["dateRep"], format="%d/%m/%Y")`.